Marker artefacting and poor rendering performance in Google Maps iOS SDK / Capacitor plugin
I have recently switched to @capacitor/google-maps plugin for Google Maps SDK to migrate my app to Capacitor Framework.
I encountered an erratic behavior with markers in the iOS implementation only (on Android it works perfectly). The markers are loading (sometimes wrong icons are shown), and when I update their position (each second, in an attempt to debug this issue), they seem to swap icons and artefacting all over the place.
This is so weird that I'm adding a video, maybe someone from Google could possibly explain what could go so wrong with the iOS SDK and/or plugin implementation: https://youtube.com/shorts/nkSTDlhLkcg?feature=share
What can be observed from the demo and is part of the unwanted and unexplained behavior:

markers are randomly swapping icons at each update
at some point, there are even partially rendered markers artefacting on the map
[update] this happens when there are many markers on the map (less than 100 anyway), as soon as I remove them (or they are less than 20 or so), the problem magically disappears, and as soon as I re-add them, the bug appears again

I attach some relevant code (Swift), with some additions that are not in the original plugin:
// function to update marker position
func updateMarkerPosition(id: String, position: LatLng) throws {
    if let marker = self.markers[id] {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: position.lat, longitude: position.lng)
        }
    } else {
        throw GoogleMapErrors.markerNotFound
    }
}

private func decodeBase64ToUIImage(base64String: String) -> UIImage? {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage(data: data)
}

// function to attach a base64 image as a marker icon
private func buildMarker(marker: Marker) -> GMSMarker {
    let newMarker = GMSMarker()
    newMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: marker.coordinate.lat, longitude: marker.coordinate.lng)
    newMarker.title = marker.title
    newMarker.snippet = marker.snippet
    newMarker.isFlat = marker.isFlat ?? false
    newMarker.opacity = marker.opacity ?? 1
    newMarker.isDraggable = marker.draggable ?? false
    newMarker.zIndex = marker.zIndex
    if let iconAnchor = marker.iconAnchor {
        newMarker.groundAnchor = iconAnchor
    }

    if let iconUrl = marker.iconUrl {
        if iconUrl.starts(with: "data:image") {
            let base64String = iconUrl.components(separatedBy: ",").last ?? ""
            if let base64Image = decodeBase64ToUIImage(base64String: base64String) {
                print("Adding new icon for marker: \(marker.uniqueID)")
                newMarker.icon = getResizedIcon(base64Image, marker)
            }
        }
    }

// function to add a marker on the map
func addMarker(marker: Marker) throws -> String {
    var markerHash = "nil"
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            let newMarker = self.buildMarker(marker: marker)
            newMarker.map = self.mapViewController.GMapView
            self.markers[marker.uniqueID] = newMarker
            markerHash = marker.uniqueID
        }
    return markerHash
}

[UPDATE]
After setting up the icons this way, with the UIImageView the original problem seems to be fixed:
let markerView = UIImageView(image: newMarker.icon)
newMarker.iconView = markerView
newMarker.tracksViewChanges = true // this seems to do the trick

However, now I encounter a significant performance bottleneck when there are many markers on the map... (less than 100 markers anyway)
